# OWASP ZAP proxy over ssh tunnel

Tags: zap

I have remote machine running docker with owaspzap image.
When I connect directly to the machine and I run the command

```
curl http://localhost:8080
```

I get the default zap proxy homepage. However when I setup a ssh tunnel to the machine (lets say I bound local port 52000 to remote port 8080) I get an error when running

```
curl http://localhost:52000
```

> ZAP Error [java.net.ConnectException]: Connection refused
>
> Stack Trace: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)  at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:425)   at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:280)   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
>     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
>     at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.executeMethod(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.runMethod(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.send(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAuthenticated(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAndReceive(Unknown Source)
>     at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAndReceive(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread.processHttp(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

What I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I think ZAP is not recognising the URL as the one its listenning on.
It thinks its listenning on http://localhost:8080 and you are requesting http://localhost:52000 so its probably trying to connect to that port.
It might be worth trying to use the same ports on both machines?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was setting up transparent http proxy on remote box that redirected local traffic from http://localhost:5000 (or any other random free port you fancy) to http://localhost:8080 (ZAP proxy port).

Then I setup ssh tunnel from localhost:52000 to remote machine localhost:5000 and I was able to get to owasp proxy over ssh tunnel.

It seems there is something wrong with the ZAP proxy network implementation I guess - as I'm having a few other services on the box to which I'm tunneling too and ZAP proxy is the only one that requires transparent http proxy.

Comment: Please raise a bug then: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues Thanks